# LaTex notation in Database (e.g. PostgreSQL) - but rendered for human readability

Tags: database, latex, crud, mathjax, katex

How can LaTex syntax in database cells (e.g. PostgreSQL) be made human readable as mathematical notation (symbols, greek letters, etc.) on the client-side, maybe with a web-interface? How can this be achieved on client-side?

Scenario:
The human user writes LaTex strings in the database. The objective is, that someone else (who does not know LaTex) can read mathematical notation on the web-browser that retrieves the entries from the database (CRUD).

- Example for web-based **mathematical notation** of LaTex:
  For example like this one (but which does *not relate to an underlying own database*): http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic-2.html . Example: The system gets the LaTex string "$\alpha$" (which would be stored in the database cell) and immedately prints out the nicely formated greek letter.
- Example for web-based **database application** (CRUD): Such a webbrowser-based client-interface is e.g. "[Portofino](http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en)"; but it does *not render LaTex* for mathematical notation. Though, the Portofino interface can be customized using the *Groovy* scripting language, but I do not know how. Does anyone know how Groovy could be used to implement *MathJax* or *KaTex*?

So the basic idea is to "merge" the concepts of these two examples into one solution. Or would you propose a different strategy?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PostgreSQL. You can store LaTeX formatted strings in PostgreSQL, but the rendering into a mathematics script happens on the client side

Comment: @Patrick - exactly. How can this be realised client-side? Is there for example maybe a web-interface solution? Or is there a software that reads latex from the database and outputs it as math notation (e.g. pgAdmin3 add-on)?

Comment: pgAdmin III does not have such support, as far as I know. You are more likely to find a renderer in a server-side web environment, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: live comparison of current capabilietis of KaTex and MathJax: http://www.intmath.com/cg5/katex-mathjax-comparison.php

Comment: So, are you asking about how to use KaTeX or MathJax or some other library (there's also MathQuill, jqMath and old jsMath and also some libraries that generate SVG and MathML)? Each library has its own documentation.. like https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX You certainly have to edit your question so that it's clear what you're asking about and without excessive details (the database part sounds like that).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no PostgreSQL client applications that support rendering of LaTeX, let alone render mathematical formulas in LaTeX format.

In a web environment [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) seems the way to go. Since it is based on JavaScript it runs in all modern browsers (that do not have JavaScript blocked).

You would query the PostgreSQL database for your LaTeX formatted formula, just like you would for any other text data, and then feed that to the MathJax processor.

Comment: MathJax is wonderful, but nowadays I'm recommending KaTeX from Khan Academy because it performs better: https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MathJax and KaTeX, but them being JavaScript libraries, you can integrate them in your web application. Specifically, in Portofino all forms are rendered with a library called Elements, which ensures that all form fields have a HTML id and a fixed HTML structure and CSS class, jQuery is included, so it is very easy to replace a given field's content with a TeX-rendered formula. You have to know JavaScript, of course.

Groovy has nothing to do with the above stuff, because Groovy is server-side, while the aforementioned technologies are client-side.

That said, this is only one side of the question. The other side is, how are values input into the database? Does the user (or the software) insert TeX strings directly? More broadly, what do you want to achieve? Because, as it is, your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Thank you Alessio. The scenario is as follows: The human user writes LaTex strings in the database. The objective is, that someone else (who does not know LaTex) can read mathematical notation on the web-browser.

Comment: Since MathJax and KaTex are just platforms that can be imported with html tags, is it possible to just implement one of these in the release of Portofino by default?

- MathJax: http://www.mathjax.org/
- KaTex: http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to discuss this, but - no, I wouldn't put it in Portofino by default, because it is too specific and it is very easy for users to add. Otherwise we should include all sorts of JavaScript libraries for various narrow use cases, and that would become a maintenance nightmare.